# Why is Ask Ubuntu not using elasticsearch for searching its content?

Tags: support, search

I am asking because I am new to Elasticsearch. So, I want to know more technicalities.

Answer (score 11):

Stack Exchange network of sites, which includes Ask Ubuntu, are actually using elasticsearch search engine.

You can read some more about it:

- [A new search engine for Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange)

---

There is also a little section about elasticsearch used in Stack Exchange in Nick Craver's blog post on [Stack Overflow's architecture](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/02/17/stack-overflow-the-architecture-2016-edition/).